# Applications folder refers to file that don't exist

Tags: hard-drive

I have a corrupt hard disk I am looking at through Recovery Mode. I initially wanted to just create a tar of the disk on a backup and call it good.

When trying to do so, tar started failing because of a file in the Applications folder which it tried to copy but then couldn't start. I thought this was pretty weird, doing an `ls` in the Applications folder doesn't show the file.

I figured this might be the corrupt part of the disk, so maybe it could be resolved just by copying the Applications folder to somewhere else, deleting the Applications folder, and recreating it.

I did an `mv Applications/* ApplicationsBackup` and everything went through except for the same file which it complained didn't exist.

I then tried to `rm -rf Applications` with `csrutil` disabled, but I was not allowed; says "Operation not permitted".

What is the interpretation of all this?

Comment: Instead of attempting to remove files/folders in a potentially corrupted area then remove it so `tar` can continue, just exclude it?  Also, why archive the whole drive and not just the User directories where the changes were made?

Comment: @Allan Just excluding the file in question doesn't work, leads to the same error. It's true I could archive just the relevant parts, but, now I've found what looks like the corruption I'm hopeful if I can just resolve that, the disk might start working and I'll have saved myself a lot of effort. And the relative who handed this computer off to me to 'fix' will be a lot happier too if I don't just give them a reformatted disk.

Comment: Also just generally, isn't it interesting that * finds files that ls doesn't, I know basically anything could happen with corrupt files, but I still think it's very strange.

Comment: I'm assuming this is a spinning HDD.  The first thing to do is check S.M.A.R.T. status.  Run this command `diskutil info diskX | grep -i smart` where `X` is the number of the drive in question.  Anything but "Verified" means your drive is physically flailing.  However, that's just a quick check; you could have a false positive.  Get a free util like [DiskDrill](https://www.cleverfiles.com/) and use their tools for a comprehensive scan and SMART report.

Comment: Once you figure out whether you have a hardware issue or a file system issue, you can then proceed.  Doing this in the "hopes" of making a drive last longer is a sure way to end up losing data.  Right now, I'd focus on your data first.  If you absolutely must copy everything, use `dd`.  Example:  `dd -if /dev/diskX -of /path/to/disk_image.img`

Comment: That SMART thing says 'Verified'. What you say is good advice, I actually backed up everything after you pointed out I could just circumvent the issue I was having. I still want to understand the original thing though. In a sense I'm less interested in fixing the computer, because I already early on extracted the actually relevant data and gave it to my relative.

Comment: What OS are you on? In the newer ones [ones I don't have great familiarity with, tbh] Apple apps are not actually where they appear to be. The OS makes it look like they're in Applications, but actually they're in the sealed system volume. idk exactly how this works from Terminal, but I imagine not well.